# Cannot determine if team is App Store or Enterprise via the App Store Connect API (yet)

Tags: ios, mobile, fastlane

I am maintaining an app that is deployed to the app store. We are using Fastlane and our certificate and provisional profile has expired.

I'm trying to use `fastlane match` to generate a new certificate. I have deleted the expired certificates in the Git repo that Fastlane points to.

Running fastlane match, I get the following error:

```
[16:50:09]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
[16:50:10]: Checking out branch master...
[16:50:10]: [32m  Successfully decrypted certificates repo[0m
[16:50:10]: Verifying that the certificate and profile are still valid on the Dev Portal...
[16:50:10]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
[16:50:11]: [33mCouldn't find a valid code signing identity for distribution... creating one for you now[0m

+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         [32mSummary for cert 2.177.0[0m                                                          |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| platform                | ios                                                                                                             |
| development             | false                                                                                                           |
| generate_apple_certs    | true                                                                                                            |
| force                   | true                                                                                                            |
| api_key_path            | **** |
| username                |  redacted                                                                                             |
| team_id                 | redacted
| keychain_path           | /Users/jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db                                                              |
| keychain_password       | ********                                                                                                        |
| skip_set_partition_list | false                                                                                                           |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

[16:50:11]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
+---------------+------+
|     [33mLane Context[0m     |
+---------------+------+
| PLATFORM_NAME |      |
| LANE_NAME     | beta |
+---------------+------+
[16:50:11]: [31mCannot determine if team is App Store or Enterprise via the App Store Connect API (yet). Set 'in_house' on your Spaceship::ConnectAPI::Token. Or set 'in_house' in your App Store Connect API key JSON file. Or set the 'SPACESHIP_CONNECT_API_IN_HOUSE' environment variable to 'true'. View more info in the docs at https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/[0m
```

Wondering if anyone has seen this before and has any idea what it means?

Thanks

PS - first time posting so appreciate any tips

UPDATE

I have managed to resolve this issue. Our build goes through Jenkins so I had to add `in_house:false`  to our App Store Connect API key JSON file.

Comment: You should move your update to an answer and mark it as the accepted one. Not only will this make it show up as **solved** in search results, but you'll also get the karma for yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I have managed to resolve this issue. Our build goes through Jenkins so I had to add in_house:false to our App Store Connect API key JSON file.